# Creating task in Gradle + Spring Boot to set default profile?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I just want to set the default profile when I run gradleRun, but this is failing with `cannot find method run()`

I'm first wondering:

What does the buildscript do for me and how can I successfully use the spring-boot plugin

> Could not find method bootRun() for arguments [build_74d21ufxy8p9tyrqny7v4pkut$_run_closure1@389a9e15] on root project 'core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE"
    }
}

task local {
    run { systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", "development" }
}

bootRun.mustRunAfter local

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

group = 'com.remindful'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Do you want to set the active profile when the application is run using gradle bootRun?

Comment: I want gradle bootRun to default to development and gradle bootRun production to default to production

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
task local {
    run { systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", "development" }
}
bootRun.mustRunAfter local
```

Add

```
bootRun {
   systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", "development"
}
```

To answer your questions about build script and spring-boot plugin, build script contains the tasks needed to build a project using gradle, this is simplistic description, check the [documentation](https://gradle.org/docs/). Spring boot plugin

> allows you to package executable jar or war archives, run Spring Boot applications, and use the dependency management provided by spring-boot-dependencies

You can refere to the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/gradle-plugin/reference/html)

Comment: Plugin with id 'spring-boot' not found.

Comment: Remove apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

Comment: Thanks, how can I have it take parameters to then run the profile I specify?

Comment: You want to set the active profile using command line arguments?